# Using Image Radio Button Style in Ionic Radio Button

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I am trying to style ionics radio button like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/La8wQ/313/

This is how we create ionic radio button normally:

```
  <ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="cards">

         <ion-item >
           <ion-label class="someclass" >text</ion-label>
           <ion-radio   value="textsradio"></ion-radio>
         </ion-item>

</ion-list>
```

with classic css and html its like this:

```
   <div class="cc-selector">


       <input checked="checked" id="visa" type="radio" name="credit-card" value="visa" />
       <label class="drinkcard-cc visa" for="visa"></label>

       <input id="mastercard" type="radio" name="credit-card" value="mastercard" />
       <label class="drinkcard-cc mastercard"for="mastercard"></label>
</div>
```

How can i do this with ionic radio button component ?

Answer (score 2):

**ion-list->ion-radio->radio-icon you can trace this by inspecting the element**

```
.list .item-radio .radio-icon {
    background-color: rgb(233, 233, 241);
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/lXzJ1eB.png);
    color: white;
  }
```